# Правильно ли взяты в кавычки слова?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

От него не требовалось ломать голову и что­-либо создавать или чертить, или даже писать, а только отрицать решения конструктора, заявляя, что это «нетехнологично», а это «мы не можем», и не подписывать чертеж, служа постоянным тормозом, а не двигателем прогресса и понуждая конструктора к примитивизму.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложила так, с запятой после "а не двигателем прогресса":

> От него не требовалось ломать голову и что­-либо создавать или чертить, или даже писать, а только отрицать решения конструктора, заявляя, что «это нетехнологично», «а это мы не можем», и не подписывать чертеж, служа постоянным тормозом, а не двигателем прогресса, и понуждая конструктора к примитивизму.

Comment: Мне кажется, что союз "а" включать в кавычки не стоит.

Comment: Нет, не думаю. Здесь идет перечисление того, что _он_ заявлял. Если "а" не включается в цитату, тогда логичнее ипользовать здесь "и":  _заявляя, что «это нетехнологично», и «это мы не можем»_ или даже _заявляя, что «это нетехнологично», и «а это мы не можем»_

Comment: Здесь "а'' входит в речь автора, поэтому он заключается в кавычки.

Answer (score 0):

> От него **не требовалось** ломать голову и что­-либо создавать или
>   чертить, или даже писать, а только **отрицать** решения конструктора...

Правильным, на мой взгляд, был бы примерно такой вариант:

*От него не требовалось ломать голову и что­-либо создавать или чертить, или даже писать. Требовалось только отрицать решения конструктора...*

**P.S.**

Вместо "требовалось" можно написать "достаточно было", "можно было"...

Answer (score 0):

Как отмечено у slava, предложение требует обязательной корректировки, его грамматическая основа обозначена неверно.

Один из возможных вариантов:

От него не требовалось ломать голову и что¬-либо создавать или чертить, или даже писать, А НУЖНО БЫЛО (ТРЕБОВАЛОСЬ)  только отрицать решения конструктора, заявляя, что это «нетехнологично», а это «мы не можем»,  и не подписывать чертеж, служа постоянным тормозом, а не двигателем прогресса и понуждая конструктора к примитивизму.

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки уместны, так как передают точные слова и выражения, которые должны быть использованы "тормозом прогресса" для достижения цели.

Однако предложение в целом перегружено запятыми. Его необходимо слегка изменить и разделить на несколько отдельных конструкций с использованием, например, парцелляции. После слова *создавать* нужна запятая по правилу постановки знаков препинания при однородных членах с повторяющимися союзами.

***От него не требовалось ломать голову и что­-либо создавать, или чертить, или даже писать. Ему надо было только отвергать решения конструктора, заявляя, что это «нетехнологично», а это «мы не можем».  Не подписывать чертеж... Иными словами, служить постоянным тормозом, а не двигателем прогресса и понуждать таким образом конструктора к примитивизму.***